# .doc file generated with php doesn't show images when open with microsoft word app

Tags: php, html, phpdoc

this is my code to generate .doc

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.doc");
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Saves as a Word Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>
some text.....
<br />
<img src="logo.jpg" border="0" alt="Logo" />
</p>
<p>
<ul>
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
</ul>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, when i open the generated .doc file, the image doesn't showed up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the image is located somewhere else.  It is basically foreign to your .doc.  When you opened it.  It was probably in a temp folder somewhere and couldn't locate "logo.jpg" image.

Comment: so any other way to make the image including inside the .doc file ? i've tried using embeded image in the php/html content. but when open in word app it shows the encoding data of the image instead of show the real image.

Comment: if you have a real link to "logo.jpg" in your code, .doc file will be able to download it, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. You're embedding a piece of text saying
`<img src="logo.jpg" border="0" alt="Logo" />` in the document, you're not embedding the image itself. In addition, you are not generating a .doc file. You're generating a .html file with a .doc extension, which is bad form. You'll need to look up an actual way to generate .doc files, my guess is you'll need to use OpenOffice in commandline form to convert from some other format you can create via code.

Answer (score 0):

all is right but when inserted image is deleted from folder i mean from source then word document does not show up your image so it is just html reader not creation of ms word doc file..